# System.IO.FileNotFoundException error to build Android project in Xamarin.Forms

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I am not able to build my Android project of Xamarin.Form. However, iOS project works fine.

I have tried by remove all DLLs from Package and Bin folders but it doesn't work.

Can anybody guide me?

> Error: Exception while loading assemblies:
>   System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load assembly 'Xamarin.iOS,
>   Version=0.0.0.0, Culture: neutral, PublicKeyToken=84exxxxxxxx'.
>   Perhaps it doesn't exist in the Mono for Android Profile?

[image]

Comment: as Exception message states, somewhere in your code you are referencing `Xamarin.iOS` library, but compiler can't find it.

Comment: @vasily.sib Exactly, even if I try to double click to redirect but it doesn't show location. can you please guide?

Answer (score 1):

I suspect the issue has something to do with you by mistake adding Xamarin.iOS dll into the Android project

Since Xamarin.iOS is a native iOS dll it will not work in Xamarin.Android

- Solution Under your project section for Android look for References.
- Under References try to find if there is a Reference for Xamarin.iOS
- If Yes then Remove it by Right clicking on the reference and selecting remove, If not then Revert

Goodluck!

Comment: Yes Open your Android project in project look for references under references look for Xamarin.iOS, Do you Understand?

Comment: I have checked, nothing is related with Xamarin.iOS. I have added screenshot of my References in Android Project

Comment: Check if the ones that are referenced by Android the ones that you have  marked out contain a reference for Xamarin.Ios

Answer (score 0):

Seems like some nuget package in your droid project is confused, remove them all and DLL references, and add them back one by one (this is what I'd do).

Or you could put your build verbosity on detailed and search through it and try and work it out from there.

Comment: I am bit confuse here as it show Xamarin.iOS error in Android project. Can you please suggest if I need to follow any specific order to install?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your Android project is referencing some other project, which is referencing `Xamarin.iOS`. Look at your projects in your solution. Each one have a **References** folder in **Solution Explorer**. Which of them contains a `Xamarin.iOS` references? I bet you erroneously reference this project in your Android project

Comment: it is named `Xamarin.iOS`

Comment: it is not in your `Droid` project. It suppose to be in 1 of 3 projects that you are censored. Can you show their references?

Comment: no, I'm talking about our `ProjectName.Droid` references (which is shown on screenshot). First 3 lines is: **<censored>**, **<censored>.Interfaces** and **<censored>.WebAPI.Models**, I belive one of this 3 projects are referencing `Xamarin.iOS`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/171540/discussion-between-vasily-sib-and-developer).